# After upgrade to 22.04 Bluetooth Devices can't connect while PulseAudio isn't running, but no Audio while PulseAudio is running

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, 22.04, a2dp, pipewire

Before upgrading to 22.04 I was able to pair my phone to my PC and stream music to my headphones.
Now when I try to connect my phone it instantly disconnects.
If I try to connect with Blueman-Manager it gives me this error:

`blueman-manager 22.07.07 WARNING  ManagerDeviceMenu:141 fail      : fail g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError:  br-connection-profile-unavailable (0)`

I found [this Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=270465) thread discussing the problem and some users suggesting it happens when PulseAudio is stopped.

So I tried starting it with `systemctl start --user pulseaudio`. As soon as I do this I can connect my phone as normal and it sees my PC as a Bluetooth speaker, but I'm not unable to hear any audio.

I can see in the log for PulseAudio whenever I try to play a sound it says:

```
Aug 23 22:09:03 Tiles-PC pulseaudio[12311]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Aug 23 22:09:03 Tiles-PC pulseaudio[12311]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Aug 23 22:09:03 Tiles-PC pulseaudio[12311]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
```

If I restart I can see in `htop` that PulseAudio isn't running at all, but I can hear audio just fine normally. I believe in 22.04 Ubuntu integrated PipeWire to some degree but I'm not sure how or if PulseAudio is still in use.

My question is:

- How do I fix A2DP / Bluetooth in Ubuntu 22.04 so I can stream audio to my PC again?
- If that requires using PulseAudio how do I make my sound work while it's running? Do I need to switch back to PulseAudio from PipeWire and how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling I disabled Pipewire and Pipewire-pulse and re-enabled PulseAudio, this let my audio work normally while PulseAudio is running, I guess they were conflicting. Not sure why Bluetooth audio doesn't work with Pipewire but maybe it's just a bug:

Disable Pipewire Services:

```
systemctl --user disable pipewire
systemctl --user disable pipewire-pulse
systemctl --user mask pipewire
systemctl --user mask pipewire-pulse
```

Enable Pulseaudio:

```
systemctl --user start pulseaudio
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
```

For me this just seemed to pick up all audio devices and carry on as normal, except now my phone will connect through Bluetooth and I can stream audio to my PC again. Not sure what the other consequences are for disabling Pipewire but i'll list any I experience here:

1. Seems like Pipewire was used for screen recording with the built in gnome screenshot program so that doesn't work anymore.
2. Pulse Audio doesn't start on boot and I have to manually start it each time before my audio works. `systemctl --user start pulseaudio`

Comment: Have you being able to use microphone from your earphones? Bluetooth connects just fine, but no mic is available...

Comment: @OleksiiPasichnyk Sorry, I haven't tried a Bluetooth microphone or headphones